# Aurelia IE11 Symbol polyfill error

Tags: aurelia

We are planning to use Aurelia in our new product and trying do simple POC Aurelia example and i am facing issue in IE11. Can any one help with this issue.

Thanks for your help.

I have created this example using below commands from [this link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/04/07/aurelia-hello-world-with-asp-net-5.aspx):

```
jspm install aurelia-framework
jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper
```

**Error:**

**Cannot define property 'Symbol(id)_h.zlr3taf0m51': object is not extensible**

**package.json**

```
{
    "jspm": {
         "directories": {
              "lib": "src"
     },
    "dependencies": {
        "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^0.11.0",
        "aurelia-framework": "^0.10.0",
        "aurelia-logging-console": "^0.3.0",
        "es6-collections": "github:webreflection/es6-collections@master",
        "mutationobservers": "github:polymer/mutationobservers@^0.4.2"
    }
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello from Aurelia</title>
    </head>
    <body aurelia-app>

<div class="splash">
    <div class="message">Aurelia Navigation Skeleton</div>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>

<script src="jspm_packages/github/webreflection/es6-collections@master/es6-collections.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/github/polymer/mutationobservers@0.4.2/MutationObserver.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/github/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@0.5.5/HTMLImports.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('main').catch(console.error.bind(console));     
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ConsoleAppender} from 'aurelia-logging-console';
import {bootstrap} from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

LogManager.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender());
LogManager.setLevel(LogManager.levels.debug);

export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .defaultBindingLanguage()
        .defaultResources()
        .router()
        .eventAggregator()

        aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body));
}
```

app.js

```
export class App {

  constructor() {
      this.message = "";
  }
  activate() {
    this.message = "Hello, World!";
  }
  changeMessage() {
    this.message = "Goodbye!";
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>${message}</div>
    <button click.trigger="changeMessage()">Say Goodbye</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I've pulled this from the [skeleton navigation](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation)

> Note: At present there is a bug in the HTMLImports polyfill which only occurs on IE. We have submitted a pull request to the team with the fix. In the mean time, if you want to test on IE, you can work around the issue by explicitly adding a script tag before you load system.js. The script tag should look something like this (be sure to confirm the version number)

```
<script src="jspm_packages/github/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@0.5.2/HTMLImports.js"></script>
```

I haven't personally tested it but it sounds like the solution to your problem.